# Find the nth number in the increasing sequence formed by 0,2,4,6,8?

Tags: algorithm, sequence, sequences

We have an increasing sequence in which each element is consist of even digits only (0, 2, 4, 6, 8). How can we `find the nth number in this sequence`

Is it possible to find nth number in this sequence in O(1) time.

Sequence: `0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 200, 202 and so on.`

Comment: where n is start form zero or one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a dump of a homework assignment that shows ZERO effort from the OP.

Comment: Your first stop on the web when looking at this exact *type* problem is the [On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](https://oeis.org), which has [this to say for the sequence 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 40, 42](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C+2%2C+4%2C+6%2C+8%2C+20%2C+22%2C+24%2C+26%2C+28%2C+40%2C+42&language=english&go=Search).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The nth number in this sequence is n in base 5, with the digits doubled.

```
def base5(n):
    if n == 0: return
    for x in base5(n // 5): yield x
    yield n % 5

def seq(n):
    return int(''.join(str(2 * x) for x in base5(n)) or '0')

for i in xrange(100):
    print i, seq(i)
```

This runs in O(log n) time. I don't think it's possible to do it in O(1) time.

It can be simplified a bit by combining the doubling of the digits with the generation of the base 5 digits of n:

```
def seq(n):
    return 10 * seq(n // 5) + (n % 5) * 2 if n else 0
```

Comment: @Paul Hankin : Sir may you please help me with how did you solved this sequence ?

Comment: @Ram it's not much help to you, but I saw straight away the relationship with numbers in base 5, and from there, writing the code is relatively straightforward. Lasse in the comments above suggested checking the sequence in OEIS -- that'd be a good way to find the pattern if you didn't see it.

Answer (score -2):

```
int Code()
{
    k=0;
   for(i=0;i<=10000;i++)
   {
       count=0;
       n=i;
       while(n!=0)
       {
           c=n%10;
           n=n/10;
           if(c%2!=0)
           {
               count=1;
           }
       }
       if(count==0)
       { a[k]=i;
       k++;}
    }
 }
```